# How to measure test coverage of LESS/CSS?

Tags: css, less, code-coverage

We have a LESS codebase with code like

```less
// my-theme.less
@brand-color: #c0ffee;
@button-background: @brand-color;
```

and (JavaScript/mocha) tests that assert that the "mappings" in this codebase are correct, e.g. that `@button-background` is mapped to `@brand-color`, like

```js
import {parameterValueInTheme} from './my-test-utils.mjs';

describe('button-background', function() {
  it('should be mapped to "@brand-color"', function() {
    assert.equal(parameterValueInTheme('@button-color', 'my-theme'), '@brand-color');
  });
});
```

Now we would like to measure the actual coverage of our tests, i.e. the percentage of LESS lines/statements covered by our unit tests.

**Has this already been done? Is there a coverage tool for LESS (like nyc/istanbul for JavaScript)?** The question could be broadened to CSS instead of LESS (or SCSS or any precompiler), as the problem seems to be really similar.